# Storing object in python dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, dictionary, logging

I have multiple log files in which I need to log based on the incoming data stream. I have initialized log objects as :-

```
logit_dict = dict()  # logit_dict is global
```

Immediately after initialization when I print dict, I could see all the objects got created and stored successfully.

```
{'11279874': "logging.Logger object at 0xb68e4dcc",
 '1464194': "logging.Logger object at 0xb6930cac",
 '11219458': "logging.Logger object at 0xb6930b8c",
 '12333058': "logging.Logger object at 0xb6930c0c"}
```

**I have removed angel brackets as the text inside that was not coming

When I am using logit_dict inside a function with key to actually log the information then I am getting KeyError.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the right type? `logit_dict['1464194']` is different to `logit_dict[1464194]` the latter being a `KeyError`. Or perhaps you a reinitializing `logit_dict` in your function and really need `global logit_dict` in the function.

Comment: provide the code that generate KeyError

Comment: BTW, your problem with \[\] is because they are used to embed links in text, so they need to be escaped when you want that character. See the formatting help for more info.

Comment: Thanks !! @ AChampion.  It got caught in "logit_dict['1464194'] is different to logit_dict[1464194]"